# restrict scopes of local variables in python

Tags: python, namespaces

When there is a long function, how to limit the scope of variables within only a section of the function? I know in many languages one can do this with {}. How to do this in python?

I am aware that a separate function for just that section will encapsulate variables to its local namespace. But for a long, linear function, many people argue that it does not make sense to write many functions (and thus names) that are only called once.

Comment: why do you want to limit the scope of variables? are you re-using them?

Comment: I'd say almost everybody argues that writing short, concise functions is almost better.

Comment: You could delete the variables when you're done with them, if you really want to. But writing smaller functions is a much better answer.

Comment: There is a new trend to ditch OO and revert back to procedural programming, not necessarily functional. It makes some sense in certain cases, such as scientific computing.

Comment: If I answered your question to your satisfaction, you can accept by answer by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.

Comment: @depperm I know old thread ... but for example ... I just found code like (adding brackets because single line) `for l in list: { if l.name: {str = l.name} otherlist.append(str)} `. Yes it's horrible code regardless of scoping, but I would at least love some sort of warning here from some linter that str can be unreferenced if name is None.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, you can't. Python only creates scopes for modules (files, generally), classes, and functions; variables can have a more limited lifetime only in a few special cases, like the `target_list` in a list comprehension in Python 3. There's no block-level scope like in Perl.

So, your possible workarounds are:

- Create single-use functions or classes. The function would have to be called, whereas the class would never have to be named again after its definition, because class definitions are executed immediately.
- `del` variables when you're done with them.

Fun fact: coming to terms with this limitation of Python is what finally got us to get rid of `let` in [Hy](http://hylang.org), because there's no way to make it work as one would expect. Update 5 years later: yet another version of `let` is implemented, and the way it works is by implementing our own entire system for tracking the scopes of variables, and enforcing it by issuing compile-time errors and adding `nonlocal` and `global` when needed. I guess there are no shortcuts here.

Comment: "Create single-use functions or classes", do you have some example pls?

Comment: @athos `def f(): …` followed by `f()`, or `class C: …`.